# How can I cast unicode string to int?

Tags: php, utf-8, casting

My code is :

```
<?php

   echo((int)("١٩")); //Number is 19

?>
```

but, output is 0 instead of 19.

Comment: why on earth are you using non-ascii values to represent numbers?

Comment: @iam-decoder values send to the server by users.

Comment: @iam-decoder and i dont know that value is ascii or not!

Comment: you can try `custom function`, By using `str_replace`.

Comment: if people are gonna type in utf-8 characters for numbers then they're expecting it to not work. no app EVER accounts for every single possible combination to figure out what the hell the user is actually trying to do. If this is from more than 1 user, then you can do a `preg_replace()` for utf-8 encodings, but it won't be fun to write

Comment: This has nothing to do with "UTF-8" as such; you're really asking how to *translate* Bangla numbers to Arabic numbers.

Comment: post shows no effort, person is asking for upvotes so that he can post questions again in chat.

Answer (score 5):

Make two array of two types number, the use the `str_replace` function. I use the Bangla character for this example, you must change it to your language.

```
function convert_number($your_num){
    $find = array("০", "১", "২", "৩", "৪", "৫", "৬", "৭", "৮", "৯");
    $replace = array("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9");
    return str_replace($find, $replace, $your_num);
}
```

Just call the function where you need to convert your number.

```
echo convert_number("১৯");
```

> Outoput: 19

Answer (score 4):

PHP casting rely on `strtod` and will only manage ascii and not ARABIC-INDIC UTF-8 characters althought they mean digits; as there is no conversion from those characters casting them will return zero.

You should test against to something like `\x{0660}-\x{0669}` (the digits codes) convert them to ascii equivalents and then cast to proper type.

Comment: tnx, but this is a bad idea!

Comment: Perhaps you should constrain user input then.

Comment: but user input is true!

Comment: The problem here isn't if the user input is true or not, we assume it is. The matter is that the systems "as it is now" doesn't know how to handle that input the way you want; so either you handle it (whatever way you like) after collection, or force the user to give the input in a format the systems recognizes.

Comment: @Muihlinn, php casting accepts an unicode string so it should or reject the call due to the portion of unicode which is non ascii before to call strtod(const char *restrict nptr, char **restrict endptr), or interpret the unicode as all user of unicode might type. Is not about relying on strtod in libc; in the way php accept the string it should do some verification before to rely on strtod which is defined for ascii only.

Comment: 1, utf-8 is 0x31, ١, utf-8 is 0x0661. Discarding won't help as it seems to be  a glyph. Anyway, I'm not an expert in unicode standards.

Answer (score 1):

@javadaskari, for now fix it as @Frayne Konok 's function convert_number, you can apply it even if the input number is ascii (it will remain valid).

Then I see reasonable you to open a bug in https://bugs.php.net saying that since (int)"string" started to accept utf-8 string, it should have accepted those characters meaning number. Php is likely to handle generic user input and the case you identified might encounter other use of that function that behave in a manner unexpected by the user.

But I don't grant that the bug you seem to have discovered will be "fixed" in php as me and you see reasonable, also I let you check there if is duplicate.